# Wordpress bool(false) means taxonomy compare not working

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement, boolean

I have a loop pulling in a wordpress content page  'peopleformat'.

Here is that loop

```
<?php
    // Start the Loop.
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
    $do_not_duplicate[] = $post->ID;
        /*
         * Include the post format-specific template for the content. If you want to
         * use this in a child theme, then include a file called called content-___.php
         * (where ___ is the post format) and that will be used instead.
         */
    get_template_part( 'content', 'peopleformat' );
?>
    <!--Get all the rest of the posts to display  -->
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php
    // 2nd loop 
    $args = array( 'post_type' => 'profile', 'posts_per_page' => 300, 'order' => 'DESC' );
    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
    if (in_array($post->ID, $do_not_duplicate)) continue;

?>
```

Within the people format page I am comparing two variables. If they are the same then ' do something'

```
<?php 
    $acf_tax = get_field('key_person');
    $custom_tax = get_taxonomy( $Team );
    if($acf_tax === $custom_tax) :
?>
```

However after doing a var_dump( $acf_tax, $custom_tax ), it comes up with bool(false) bool(false) . And im not sure how to stop from being a bool? And finding the values properly?

The end goal i would like to achieve is if acf_tax and custom_tax have the same value then it will 'do something'.

Answer (score 0):

From a variables name they suppose to have type float. like 9.97
so you can do like this;

```
   $acf_tax = (float)get_field('key_person');
   $custom_tax = (float)get_taxonomy( $Team );
   if($acf_tax === $custom_tax)
```

So, they gonna be float